# How to get the cosine similarity score of a Query for a Document

Tags: python, python-3.x, tf-idf, cosine-similarity

I am doing a Text Classification program, in which I have a Dataset of 5 classes('business', 'entertainment', 'local', 'sports', 'world'). The Dataset contains 5 folders (for 5 classes) of 100 txt files. My requirement is, when I insert a text file (a query), I want to check whether this file has similarity to any of the 5 classes or does not fit any of the classes.

For this, I planned to write a python code. For which I find the TFIDF for the five classes (using the 100 text files each ), and finding a mean for each specific class and the using a cousin similarity for the TFIDF if the new text file. And get a cosine similarity score. This score I mentioned was a single number, not cousin similarity to each word. Meaning when we compare the text file to any of a class, the entire document, the inserted text file's similarity score should give a number. (example, score = 5).

But I am having a hard time writing a python3 code for this, can anyone help me out writing this code to get cosine similarity score for a Document(set of text file) and a text file(query).

Here is what i have done so far,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
#importing test, train data
from  sklearn.datasets import load_files

sinhala_entertainment = load_files('Testing data set\stemmed_filtered_sinhala-set1\entertainment', encoding= 'utf-8')

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer

count_vectorization = CountVectorizer()
tfidf_trans = TfidfTransformer()

entertainment_data_tf = count_vectorization.fit_transform(sinhala_entertainment.data)
entertainment_data_tfidf = tfidf_trans.fit_transform(entertainment_data_tf)

sample_test1 = open("adaderana_67571.txt", encoding='utf-8')  
sample_test = sample_test1.read() 

sample_data_tf = count_vectorization.fit_transform([sample_test])
sample_data_tfidf = tfidf_trans.fit_transform(sample_data_tf)

from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
similarity = cosine_similarity(sample_data_tfidf , entertainment_data_tfidf )
```

I'm getting a error when finding the cosine similarity.
`sinhala_entertainment` is a class(contains 100 txt files) and `sample_test1` is the query.

Comment: Show us what you've already done.  We can advise you on how to extend it.

Comment: @TimRoberts I had updated my code

Answer (score 0):

last line want to be,

```
similarities_tfidf = cosine_similarity(sample_data_tfidf, entertainment_data_tfidf)[0]
```